# Why doesn't the dropdown of the combobox not update when I change the ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

While trying to alter the contents of a combobox on runtime, I stumbled upon a confusing feature.
(Please excuse the many images. I felt that they were severely needed to understand what's going on)

[image: My WPF form]

[image: My xaml for WPF form]

[image: Codebehind for the Button_Click_1 event]

Above you can see my WPF form, my xaml and the codebehind for the Button_Click_1 event.

Incase you were wondering what strings were exactly being saved into this "txt" variable, it was "jon", "ted", "tod" and "adam". As you might expect "jon" would have the index of 0, "ted" of 1, "tod" of 2 and "jon" of 3.

What I want to do is change the "List" assigned to the "ItemsSource" directly without having to reassign a new "List".

What I noticed while testing was that this is definitely possible.
Below you will see the results of me clicking on the button once.

[image: Form after clicking the button once]

What essentially is happening is that the content of the "test.txt" file is getting saved into the the "txt" variable as a "List".

This variable is then assigned to the "ItemsSource" property of the combobox.

I then proceed to alter the "ItemsSource" directly by removing the item with the index of 1 ("ted").

Lastly, I set the "SelectedIndex" to the item with the new index of 1 ("tod").

When running the program and clicking the combobox to see what items are contained inside the dropdown, I am presented with exactly those three items contained inside of the altered "ItemsSource". ("jon", "tod" and "adam")

Now it starts to get a little more confusing when I decide to click on the button again.

[image: Form after clicking the button twice]

As you can see, after clicking the button a second time, all four items of the "List" get displayed instead of the previous three.

My current theory of how the dropdown of a combobox works is that the content of the "ItemsSource" property gets saved into a sort of cashe which gets used by wpf internally to display the items of the dropdown. This saving of the content seems to also only happen on the first click of the choicebox (textbox). It is then no longer possible to change this cashe by altering the "ItemsSource" directly. Through further testing I also discovered that the only way to change/update this cashe is by assigning a whole new "List" to the "ItemsSource".

Is my theory in some way, shape, or form correct?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Which behavior should the program have?

Comment: Yes you are right. if you make change directly in `ItemSource` like you did. But if you want to reflect these changes then use `INotifyPropertyChanged`Interface to raise `PropertyChanged` event that will automatically update. or another way is what you already know assigning an `empty List` and then real data.

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of a `List<string>`; this will inform the combobox whenever an item is added or removed.

Comment: @Rias
I had no real goal in mind for this program. I just wanted to know what exactly was happening behind the scenes for WPF to display such functionality.